# On factoring polynomials whose only coefficients are 0 and 1.

Tags: polynomials, factoring, rational-functions, cyclotomic-polynomials

I say a polynomial $P\left(z\right)=\sum_{n=0}^{d}a_{n}z^{n}$ is **digital** if for each $n$, $a_{n}\in\left\{ 0,1\right\}$.

Let $\alpha$ be a positive integer $\geq2$, and let $P\left(z\right)$ be a non-zero digital polynomial of degree $d$, where $d\leq\alpha-1$. Supposing that $P\left(z\right)$ and $1-z^{\alpha}$ are *not* co-prime, let: $$\frac{N\left(z\right)}{D\left(z\right)}$$
denote the irreducible form of the rational function: $$\frac{P\left(z\right)}{1-z^{\alpha}}$$
where both $N\left(z\right)$ and $D\left(z\right)$ are monic polynomials.

Is it necessarily true that $N\left(z\right)$ will be a digital polynomial, and that $D\left(z\right)=1-z^{\beta}$, where $\beta$ is some divisor of $\alpha$?

Comment: This looks interesting.  What is the source of the question?  What have you tried so far?

Comment: I'm debugging proofs from my current research. I'm using analytic methods to characterize the amount of arithmetic structure possible in an orbit classes of the Collatz map (viz., the Collatz Conjecture), and other maps like it. Specifically, that an orbit class of such a map which contains an infinite arithmetic progression must be equal to $\mathbb{N}$. I was almost certain that this proposition was true; I just wasn't quite sure how to make sure of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rational function $\, P(z)/(1-z^\alpha) \,$ is the generating function of a sequence of numbers each of which is $0$ or $1$. By construction, the sequence has a period of $\,\alpha.\,$ Let its minimal period be $\,\beta.\,$ Then $\,\beta\,$ must divide $\,\alpha\,$ because the minimal period divides all periods. The generating function is now $\, Q(z)/(1-z^\beta) \,$ where $\, Q(z) \,$ is the generating function polynomial of the repeating part of the sequence and hence is digital just as $\,P(z)\,$ was.

Comment: Yes, that's perfect. Glad to know my intuition, for once, turns out to be right! Thanks!

Comment: @mcs You are welcome. I deal with periodic sequences a lot in the context of OEIS. Thanks for asking the question.